# Will restoring WhatsApp chats from a backup also restore blocked contacts' chats?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, restore

If I want to restore my conversations on WhatsApp and I'm reinstalling it from the latest backup, will the conversations with the blocked contacts appear? Will the blocked contacts continue to be blocked?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, restoring from backup (like with Titanium Backup) will restore all conversations. App settings will be restored as well, so blocked contacts should stay blocked.

Comment: Thank you! Which means that they will still be blank? because basically if i "cleared the conversation" and then i blocked the user, even after a restore, the chats will be blank?

Comment: The chats should be in the same state as when the backup was made. So if you cleared them, they should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

The blocked numbers don't have any relation with restoring backup or not. They're stored online. So, even if you don't restore the backup, the numbers will be there in the blocked list.

Comment: chats are stored locally too